# Shared dev machine and local workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

Suppose we have a machine shared by many developers. Developers have access to different parts of the project, they don't see all the same complete source code. Suppose also that we use this shared machine even to test job interviewer on some test programs.

How do we protect source code in the local workspaces? I mean, we wouldn't want that developers/job interviewer are able to see/copy what they are not allowed to. We use Visual Studio & TFS 2012 in a Windows environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Is every deloper using his own account? Then you could store the workspace in the profile (only for small projects up to 100 MB) or you can create personel network share folders, which could not be read by other users (except admins). Another option would be, that every developer creates his workspace and than removes permission for other users.

Comment: @Mike: Are you sure there is no way to dig into another user profile? In addition the path to sources would become very complicated...

Comment: only if you have admin permission on the server, otherwise the profile folder should be yours. (c:\localuser\userAccount)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Add an answer so I can mark this as answered.

Comment: While i can understand why interviewees shouldn't be allowed to see all code, I can't help but think you're going about this weirdly. Why not create a separate virtual machine for interviews?  I also question why you would want to restrict developers reading all code, surely there could be code of use to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users do not have admin permissions, you could store the workspace in the users profile. So it is only accessible for them (and administrators). But you should be careful with this, because the size of the profile could grow extremely, which would have effect to your login time on other machines. Also some companies set a max size for profiles, which could be exceeded fast using this method.

Another option would be to store the workspace on a network share, which has personalized permissions.